# How to add MySQL to $PATH variable to resolve "mysql: command not found"?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, mysql, environment-variables

I installed MySQL on my Mac, and now I would like to add it to my `$PATH` variable. I want to be able to type `mysql` anywhere.

I tried adding the following to my `.profile` file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

I have restarted my Terminal but it does not do the trick. It still says: `-bash: mysql: command not found`.

How can I add this properly to my `$PATH`?

I am using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Path components in the PATH variable are separated by a colon in bash.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here is why your current code is not working:

```
export PATH=${PATH}/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

You forgot the colon and the trailing "/" is unnecessary.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

is the correct code.

Comment: For this to work for me, I also had to reload the .bash_profile from the command line, by running: source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Alistair's answer below is better.  If you use this without adding it permanently to the bash file, you will have to keep exporting everytime you open the terminal.

Answer (score 25):

Try adding the following line to your `.bash_profile` file.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

You can do this easily with the following command, which will append the line if the file already exists or create a new file with the line if it doesn't.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: With MAMP: `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: The is the correct way to go.  Without adding it to the bash_profile you'll have to export the path to mysql every time you open the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this by going to your .bash_profile file and adding these lines to it.

```
alias mysql.start="sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start"
alias mysql.stop="sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop"
alias mysql.restart="sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart"
alias mysql.status="sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status"
```

After you've done this you can start, stop, restart and check the status of your connection anywhere in your terminal like this:

```
mysql.start - starts mysql
mysql.stop - stop mysql
mysql.restart - restarts mysql
mysql.status - checks the status of mysql
```

Hope that helps even tho I might be late. CHEERS!

Answer (score 1):

In your `.zshrc` file, just add this following line:

```
alias mysql="sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p"
```

You can now access it from anywhere by writing `mysql` in the terminal.

This will simply ask you for the password of the root user and done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an alias to do things like setting username and database.

In .bash_profile ( just .profile on some systems )

```
alias mysql='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u username --default-character-set=utf8' -p databasename
```

logout and open a new terminal or it won't get setup

Now typing `mysql` will ask for your database password and take you straight there, instead of fiddling with the options each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify your `.bash_profile` file, take a look at this article: [My Mac Osx Bash Profile](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/), which is very helpful and easy to understand.

It solved my $PATH issue (which appeared out of nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

**For MAMP users,**

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Answer (score -2):

edit the system wide configuration file:

```
/etc/paths
```

Comment: This file gets overwritten by every OS X upgrade.