# echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile by using this command getting permission denied?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I tried to follow the instructions in [How to add MySQL to $PATH variable to resolve "mysql: command not found"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176786/how-to-add-mysql-to-path-variable-to-resolve-mysql-command-not-found/401724#401724)

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
zsh: permission denied: /Users/naveenkumarp/.bash_profile
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Please run `ls -al ~/.bash_profile` and copy/paste both the command and the result *as text* into the question text.

Comment: Also, you seem to be running `zsh` so why do you want to update `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I m learning my sql I saw the command use this locate the mysql using the terminal command so I tried this

Comment: Try change `.bash_profile` to `.zshenv` in the command

Comment: @ReneLarsen By default, `>>` will create the file if it doesn't exist, so using `>` instead is not necessary. And using `>` is dangerous, because if the file *does* exist, it'll be silently and irretrievably  erased before the new content is added.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `nano` editor to edit the correct file for your shell, which is zsh, not bash.

```zsh
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Put this line in at the top of the file

```zsh
typeset -U path PATH
```

Put this line towards the bottom and save:

```zsh
path+=/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Press the control key and the X key to exit (see the bottom of the nano window for more commands). If you then quit your terminal app, you can test for `mysql` being in your path.

You can tell your shell with `echo $SHELL` and if you want bash since all your instructions are in it, you can go back to that if needed with `chsh /bin/bash` in which case you would nano the file ~/.bash_profile since each shell reads different start up files. I recommend learning `zsh` and finding guides that work there, though.

Comment: Ahem, the error message says `zsh`...

Comment: Thank you kindly for pointing my error out @nohillside - Do you think .zprofile is better than .zshrc for PATH amends?

Comment: @bmike- add the following line before your path declaration to remove duplicate search paths- `typeset -U path` or according to the zsh guide- `typeset -U path PATH`

Comment: I’m not sure of that syntax @fd0 - can you edit my answer if I don’t do it correctly? So much thanks on the help here. I tested my initial answer to be sure it didn’t break horribly

Comment: I have no experience with zsh at all :-)

Comment: @bmike - by zsh manuals the correct file for PATH is .zshenv - hoever Apple can't read the manuals and put path_helper in /etc/zprofile If you use shells only from the terminal then it does not matter which file is edited -

Answer (score -1):

Change bash_profile to zshenv. Worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).